# RuntimeException when clicking on EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a release Android App that goes smooth on a Nexus 5X running Android 6.0.1. and on a Samsung 5 running Android 5.0.

However, on other devices weird exceptions rise when **double clicking** or **long clicking** any `EditText`.

This is the track on an `Alcatel OneTouch (Android 5.1)`:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                   Process: es.solbyte.ociohoteles, PID: 18176
                                                   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class TextView
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                                                       at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.initContentView(Editor.java:3047)
                                                       at android.widget.Editor$PinnedPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:2302)
                                                       at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:3019)
                                                       at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:3019)
                                                       at android.widget.Editor$HandleView.showActionPopupWindow(Editor.java:3422)
                                                       at android.widget.Editor$InsertionHandleView.showWithActionPopup(Editor.java:3672)
                                                       at android.widget.Editor$InsertionPointCursorController.showWithActionPopup(Editor.java:3929)
                                                       at android.widget.Editor.performLongClick(Editor.java:900)
                                                       at android.widget.TextView.performLongClick(TextView.java:9104)
                                                       at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:20236)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=15; index=1570
                                                       at android.content.res.StringBlock.get(StringBlock.java:65)
                                                       at android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser.getPooledString(XmlBlock.java:458)
                                                       at android.content.res.TypedArray.loadStringValueAt(TypedArray.java:1003)
                                                       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getString(TypedArray.java:188)
                                                       at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1042)
                                                       at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:660)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:60)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:56)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:103)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:980)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1039)
                                                       at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
                                                       at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.initContentView(Editor.java:3047) 
                                                       at android.widget.Editor$PinnedPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:2302) 
                                                       at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:3019) 
                                                       at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:3019) 
                                                       at android.widget.Editor$HandleView.showActionPopupWindow(Editor.java:3422) 
                                                       at android.widget.Editor$InsertionHandleView.showWithActionPopup(Editor.java:3672) 
                                                       at android.widget.Editor$InsertionPointCursorController.showWithActionPopup(Editor.java:3929) 
                                                       at android.widget.Editor.performLongClick(Editor.java:900) 
                                                       at android.widget.TextView.performLongClick(TextView.java:9104) 
                                                       at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:20236) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

And this is the track on an `ZTE Kis II Max (Android 4.4.2)`:

```
06-29 16:37:44.361 12852-12852/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: es.solbyte.ociohoteles, PID: 12852
                                                   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class TextView
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                                                       at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.initContentView(Editor.java:2973)
                                                       at android.widget.Editor$PinnedPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:2268)
                                                       at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:2946)
                                                       at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:2946)
                                                       at android.widget.Editor$HandleView.showActionPopupWindow(Editor.java:3166)
                                                       at android.widget.Editor$SelectionModifierCursorController.initHandles(Editor.java:3690)
                                                       at android.widget.Editor$SelectionModifierCursorController.show(Editor.java:3661)
                                                       at android.widget.Editor$SelectionActionModeCallback.onCreateActionMode(Editor.java:2896)
                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView$ActionModeCallbackWrapper.onCreateActionMode(PhoneWindow.java:2811)
                                                       at android.support.v7.view.SupportActionModeWrapper$CallbackWrapper.onCreateActionMode(SupportActionModeWrapper.java:155)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7$ActionModeCallbackWrapperV7.onCreateActionMode(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1742)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.startSupportActionModeFromWindow(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:802)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.startSupportActionMode(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:696)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14$AppCompatWindowCallbackV14.startAsSupportActionMode(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:187)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14$AppCompatWindowCallbackV14.onWindowStartingActionMode(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:171)
                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.startActionMode(PhoneWindow.java:2432)
                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.startActionModeForChild(PhoneWindow.java:2419)
                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:689)
                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:689)
                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:689)
                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:689)
                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:689)
                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:689)
                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:689)
                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:689)
                                                       at android.view.View.startActionMode(View.java:4561)
                                                       at android.widget.Editor.startSelectionActionMode(Editor.java:1584)
                                                       at android.widget.Editor.performLongClick(Editor.java:877)
                                                       at android.widget.TextView.performLongClick(TextView.java:8585)
                                                       at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:18768)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=15; index=1570
                                                       at android.content.res.StringBlock.get(StringBlock.java:65)
                                                       at android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser.getPooledString(XmlBlock.java:458)
                                                       at android.content.res.TypedArray.loadStringValueAt(TypedArray.java:721)
                                                       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getString(TypedArray.java:125)
                                                       at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1002)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:60)
                                                    at android.support.v7.
```

Is someone able to explain what is this happening? Is it somehow related with the hardware/distribution?

**EDIT 1:**

Please take into account that this is a big app so I cannot post all places where it is crashing. This is an extract of the very first EditText where the app is crashing.

```
// LoginActivity.java
public class LoginActivity extends ApiActivity implements
    onLoginSuccessListener {

    @Bind(R.id.login_field_email)
    protected EditText user;

    /* OnCreate and other methods... */

    @OnTextChanged({R.id.login_field_email, R.id.login_field_password})
    public void onAnyFieldChanged() {
        loginButton.setEnabled(areFieldFilled());
    }
```

This is the content layout XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".activity.LoginActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_login">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_forms"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/login_brand"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/white">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/login_field_email"
                style="@style/EditTextLogin"
                android:hint="@string/registration_email"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
                ...
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        ...
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The `styles.xml`:

```
    <style name="EditTextLogin" parent="android:Widget.EditText">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">sans</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
        <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">44dp</item>
    </style>
```

The `build.gradle` files:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

```
android {

    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias '...'
            keyPassword '...'
            storeFile file('...')
            storePassword '...'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            useProguard false
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url "https://clojars.org/repo/" }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
}
```

And the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="es.solbyte.ociohoteles">

    <!-- All needed permissions here -->

    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:theme="@style/Base.AppTheme">

        <!-- Login -->
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.LoginActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Base.AppTheme.Login"/>

    </application>
<manifest>
```

And just in case the BaseApp theme:

```
<!-- Base -->
<style name="Base.AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Colours -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColor_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background_activity</item>
    <!-- Fonts -->
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Do you have an idea where exactly in your app this happens? Can you attach the relevant XML file?

Comment: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=15; index=1570` this line suggests that there's some kind of array somewhere messing things up. Share relevant code/xml.

Comment: @Vucko it is indeed related to some array but none of my code. It must be something internal.

Comment: @Egor this is happening on every EditText, but only when using the specified mobile devices. I will add some code like gradle build but please feel free to ask for more.

Answer (score 3):

I have same problem with editText
the problem in my case was in my style

```
        <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
            <item name="android:fontFamily" tools:targetApi="jelly_bean">sans-serif</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

my problem solved by removing this line of code

```
<item name="android:fontFamily" tools:targetApi="jelly_bean">sans-serif</item>
```

Comment: I'll check it out asap